# ASP.NET Core 2.1: Argument null exception when project is located not on windows hdd

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Sorry in advance for my bad English. I am a newbie developer, just started  learning ASP.NET Core today. In short, I ran into a problem just after creating a project. I did not add anything, it just won't start. After a couple hours of trying to understand the problem, I created new project (with folder) in my desktop folder, instead of my default projects folder (which is located on the other hdd), and it works for now. Could you please help me understand why is this happening? Thank you in advance.
[Here is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSI3g.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace proj1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

//THE EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE ↓
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you are showing is not that give exception.

Comment: Can you show more code of Startup.cs file ? It says an error occurred at line 40, can you post that line of code ?

Comment: The code here is part of the default MS Visual Studio asp.net core 2.1 template, so i felt like unnecessary to post the whole code here :)

Comment: PS Posted the whole startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line of code, `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);` is used for adding backward compatibility for the code that is in lower version if you have migrated to higher version.

This link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/introducing-compatibility-version-in-mvc/ clarifies it.

The exception tells us that it doesn't find relevant dlls in your bin(path of executing assembly) folder.

Finally as you are already working on 2.1 version, I feel there is no need to add compatibility for 2.1 itself as such.